# Test Connection for vintage lighting fitting

Tags: lighting, light-fixture

Out apartment has one of those vintage light fittings, with the edison bulbs in. It also has 4M high ceilings. One of the bulbs has popped and repeatedly pops if i replace it. so i'd like to take the fitting down from the rose and check the connections both in the base and the bulb fitting.

The question is, can I use a wall socket and a kettle lead to create a supply, so that I can work on this and test the fittings out without it hanging from the ceiling? My thinking is, that a plug, with the appropriate fuse (3A) and a long lead, would mean that i could easily test the fitting, using the switch at the wall to make it safe whilst i checked all connections.

Basically, is the 240V in the Wall Socket, the same as the 240V in the lighting circuit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **is the 240V in the Wall Socket, the same as the 240V in the lighting circuit?**

Yes, so long as you use the 3A fuse (or better yet a 1A fuse if you can find one)

I'd second ratchetfreak's advice to unplug the cable when working on the connections.

---

There are things you can buy to make the temporary wiring safer and more convenient

#### Cliff Quick-Test

[image]

#### WAGO 224 wiring connectors

[image]

---

#### Related

- [When doing electrical work, what do I use to check wires are safe?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/90038/2815)
- [Electric shock - was I stupid, unlucky, or a combination of both?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/47613/2815)

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary test setup it's fine. Assuming that you know what you are doing and you monitor the thing while it's in use.

However the switch at the wall will probably only switch the live wire while the neutral will remain connected. So it'll be safer to pull the plug out of the wall when you go to mess with the connections.

Comment: wish i could accept both answers, went for t'other one due to suggestion to use a device to make it truely safe. sorry. thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

Lamps and wall socket have the same voltage.

Before these operations you must switch off the electricity if you have not enough electrical skills  or your screwdriver has no isolation from end. Check the entry switches of your appartment and switch off the switcher responcible for ceiling illumination.

Your problem seems in poor contact between the central lamp pin and central pin of lamp socket. You just have to refine both contacts with using the Slot Type screwdriver, and then use screwdriver to unfold the central pin of lamp socket for having stronger pressure between both items. Finally you will have strong electrical contact, it mean you will have no blinking, no noise, good durability of each next lamp.

Comment: Before pulling out the fixture first "unfold the central pin" with the socket in place and try another lamp. I have sometimes used a crochet hook for this adjustment, but a flat blade screwdriver works too.