# 3 phase (delta) power to single phase space heater

Tags: electrical, 240v

I bought a 240V single phase, space heater for heating up a warehouse space.  The warehouse has 240V power in a delta configuration (no neutral).  My understanding is that in a delta configuration, the line voltage between any two phases is the same as the phase voltage, in this case, 240V.  So I should be able to wire the the heater between any two lines, right?

Comment: Thanks for everyone that helped here.  It definitely gave me a better understanding of the variety of electrical systems around as well as a confirmation of my understanding of the system currently installed in the warehouse provided by @Harper.

Answer (score 22):

### Here's what 3-phase delta looks like.

This happens to be 240V and uses the common 3-phase colors of black, red, blue.

[image]

It's that simple, folks.  3 phases, **No Neutral**.

One error of belief is thinking every service must have a neutral.  It doesn't.   This was Tesla's genius.

Delta is used in industrial facilities where a few tools need a medium amount of power for a few larger tools.  It would be rare to see lighting or other minor loads run off it.  A motor which takes 240V 3-phase can typically be jumpered to also work on 480V 3-phase, and that is much more efficient to distribute. I would never install 240V today, I'd install 480V.

Obviously there's only one voltage.  *Pretty straightforward*.  Now what's this?

[image]

**It's the exact same thing**.  The only difference is using alternate colors. The point here is that any color may be used (except white, gray or green) *including orange*.  NEC doctrine is the electrician is expected to measure the circuit to determine voltages. Prince fan? Use Purple Pink Black.

### Hook your heater between any two hots.

They are all 240V. Done.

The only other issue is balancing.  If you have several loads, try to put them on alternate phases so you load the 3 phases evenly.

We're done here.

---

---

### So what's this Other Thing then?

This thread is dominated by discussion of *some other system* which is not relevant to OP.  It's a red herring.  But since it keeps coming up, let's talk about it.  This is "high-leg" or "wild-leg" delta, which is a clever rearrangement of delta to get 120V single-phase loads also - to avoid the cost of a separate 240/120V single-phase service. See how a neutral has been **added** halfway down a phase.

[image]

If you want to use 120V appliances, this only works on 240V delta.

Notice two mandatory wire colors.  Of course, neutral must be white or gray.  The "wild leg" - with much higher voltage to neutral - must be **orange**. It's one of very few cases where a "hot" color is mandated. *However in any other circuit, you can use orange for any hot*, and that's exactly what happened in our second example. That means if you see black-red-orange-white, it could be *anything* including 600V wye.  You better test it.

So when someone says "Delta" they do not mean "wild-leg delta". They mean "delta".  Don't go buying something that needs 120V or 208V expecting it to be there in delta service.  It won't be unless they specify wild-leg/high-leg.

All the 120V loads load up the A-C phase.  If there's a desire to run a significant number of 120V circuits, 208V "wye" 3-phase does a better job of it, while allowing loads to be balanced. If lighting is the primary load, 480V "wye" is a "swiss army" voltage, allowing 240V/480V motors to run in delta connection and lighting to work in wye, using a hot-neutral 277V connection.

Comment: The wild leg is not a hack and is acknowledged by code.

Comment: Funny, this is exactly the configuration that the machine from [this older question of mine](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/183484/how-to-wire-three-phases-for-220v) required. If you and @ScotBirmingham don't mind you could add an answer to my question, stating where this 240V delta configuration is used.

Comment: @EdBeal Fixed.  I meant "hack" like "clever rearrangement".

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I understood to be true but wanted confirmation.  @AndreKR This is the power system in a warehouse space.  It's not residential.

Comment: @ScotBirmingham Neither is my machine. :)

Comment: I saw when I was looking at other topics before I posted, several people referred to a stinger leg.  I'm assuming that another alternate name for the wild leg/high leg in the other delta configuration.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you are correct. You can wire the heater across any two of the three phases.

Comment: THIS IS A DELTA!!! Phase B should be a wild leg DO NOT USE LEG B or smoke will be present.

Comment: Ed, this is an unfair down vote and incorrect. In a delta system, the phase-to-phase voltage is the same. The B phase, or high leg only becomes a problem when you are wiring a 120V load to a panel box with a 120/240 three phase high leg delta service. The voltage across the neutral and the high-leg will be 208V. That is where the smoke begins and why the wire must be orange colored. A 240V single phase load will work just fine across any two of three phases.

Comment: Two down votes by people who clearly don't understand three phase systems. Very disappointing. I want someone to prove me wrong and explain why. Otherwise this is promoting false information.

Comment: THERE IS NO HIGH LEG.  Not all Delta is high leg.  High-leg is a compromise to get 120V out of delta, and it's funny stuff that needs special handling.  Unless someone tells you it's high-leg or wild-leg, it is not.

Comment: @Harper Exactly. This is a 240V only service that most likely accompanies a separate 120/240 split phase lighting panel. Plus its a 240V load meaning that the high leg would never be an issue to begin with even if it were present.

Comment: @Harper - I don't care what someone else tells you. [Check it yourself](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47613/electric-shock-was-i-stupid-unlucky-or-a-combination-of-both/47653#47653).

Comment: @Mazura of course.  However I'm referring to design.   For instance if you hear a system is 240V delta, I am saying don't spec a 120V load presuming "since it's 240V delta it must surely be wild-leg".

Answer (score 7):

> My understanding is that in a delta configuration, the line voltage between any two phases is the same as the phase voltage, in this case, 240V.

'phase voltage' is not a great term.  It would generally be interpreted as phase-to-neutral voltage, but you said you have no neutral.

3-phase delta works like this:

[image: 3phase delta]

If you're sure you have no neutral, you can ignore the neutral in the diagram and the 120 and 208 that it can provide.

> So I should be able to wire the the heater between any two lines, right?

You should be able to wire the heater between any two hots, Yes.
Measure voltage first to make sure it's 240 like you expect.

Comment: Phase voltage is the proper term if referring to the actual phase voltage. If you took a 240V delta transformer bank apart and treated each transformer as a single phase, you would measure a 240V phase voltage. Once wired up as a delta bank, the system is now a three phase system and has a phase-to-phase voltage of 240V, the same voltage as the phase voltage. Looking at a 120/208 wye system, the phase voltage would be 120V and the phase-to-phase voltage would be 208V.

Comment: No.  You're describing "high leg" or "wild leg" delta.  Plain old 240V delta exists too.  Normal deltas can only supply the named voltage.  There is no way to tap it for fractional voltages.   People often assume there MUST be a way to derive 120V; not necessarily.  Often 120V is installed as a completely separate service.

Comment: Delta is common in older industrial areas or supplied where the customers three phase requirement is quite small, e.g. a farm or small business with a few motors. Utilities don't install new delta services unless they are maintaining an existing system or the customer explicitly requires it. Though, in rural areas it is common to find open delta banks fed from open wye primaries. Cheaper to install when a customer down the road from a set of primaries requires light three phase service. Two primary phases, and a neutral feed two cans creating a 120/240 delta.

Comment: We have delta all over the place.  Five services and none of them are wye.  Well wait, we have one wye in an office structure, mainly for lighting.

Comment: @Harper are those older buildings? Not to argue but I was under the impression that utilities are not building out any new delta systems unless they are small open delta setups for small individual or rural use. By me there is still a ton of delta as the area was developed in the 1940's. Though, newer construction for the past few decades is all wye service. Even in the delta pockets there are poles with wye banks serving newer buildings.

Comment: Two from the 60s, one 70s and one 80s at the same locations as already had it, one mid-2000s that was wye however I think we provisioned that ourselves, and one 2013 that we had to fight to get ungrounded delta.

Comment: @Harper Why would you want Delta over Wye?  Is there more to that than the cost of the forth conductor?

Comment: @BillyC. The reason is motors. Delta was popular because it delivered the full 240V which was a standard motor voltage. Back in ye olde days, factories didn't have all these fancy appliances, tools, and computers. Lighting was the majority of 120V loads. The rest were all three phase motors making the majority of the load three phase. Delta worked great in those scenarios. Wye has the disadvantage of only supplying 208V which isn't good for 240V motors so it was avoided. Once they designed motors which could handle both voltages, delta became less desirable.

Comment: @BillyC. good Q.   I work on vehicular systems where there are two electrical systems which must not interact, so one must float.  A "ground fault" is **anything** to ground.   It taught me "grounding does not equal safety and grounding *everything* is not necessarily good".  If ungrounded service ground-faults, it is now corner-grounded service and the ground strap is the fault.  On a healthy system virtually no current flows down the ground strap, so, you get a tingle and live. This works well on Delta systems which tend to be well maintained and have only a few machines.

Comment: Sorry for straying off topic.  I'll take this to meta or chat if you tell me how, but now you got me wondering @Harper.  Is this two systems for redundancy, or are you referring to hybrid or electric only, where the traction battery is kept isolated from chassis?  One of my bucket list projects is designing an interconnect between my prius and my home's electrical system to use the prius as a generator during outages that are too long for my UPS to cover.

Comment: For clarification, the warehouse has been used as a small production facility for some past tenants (a coffee roaster for one).  My understanding is that the 240V Delta system was used for them to run motors and such as @Harper has suspected.  I'm not at all sure when the power was initially installed.

Answer (score -1):

If this is a DELTA usually the B leg is colored Orange and will be 2x the standard voltage. WYE connected systems all 3 legs have the same voltage. Verify the voltages prior to making any connections!!! Added for all those that have not worked on deltas with single phase. By code the system has to be grounded and can create the wild leg. Use of a wild leg will double the voltage to ground when used with single phase. Code requires equipment like this to have the highest voltage rating not dual voltage because of the high leg. At least this is code in the U.S. that has not changed for years. So ether there is a wild leg or a corner grounded. A single phase load would need to be on one of the grounded legs.

Comment: There is no double voltage in a delta service. You are thinking of the the high leg voltage, also called bastard voltage. High leg voltage is 208V and only appears across the neutral and B phase. The neutral is derived by center tapping one of the three (or two if open delta) transformers. It also serves as the ground reference. That transformer is often physically larger and colloquially called the lighting can. It only becomes an issue when wiring up 120V loads in a panel box which is serviced by a 120/240 three phase high leg delta.

Comment: You're thinking of high leg or wild leg delta, as described in Billy C's post.  Not all delta is high-leg.  However if it is high-leg, the high leg must be orange.  It's the only restriction on "hot" color I'm aware of.

Comment: Furthermore, connecting a 240V space heater B-to-neutral in a high leg setup won't kill it, it'll just run somewhat...wimpily off the 208V present there.

Comment: *According to code* the high leg must be orange. According to my eyesight, the last place I worked at that had a high leg it was black.

Comment: Orange is the new black :)  Sorry couldn't resist!