# NCV fails to still detect voltage once the circuit is loaded?

Tags: wiring, switch, light-fixture

The light above the cooktop in our kitchen started flickering occasionally, and eventually just was steadily very dim. I hated the fixture, so thought I'd replace it, and also just hoping the connection in the fixture was bad. But, beyond troubleshooting the flickering light, I have a few questions about the switch (S1) that powers the light…

1. In the associated metal switchbox (S1), there is only a 2-wire cable, a yellow and a black (I guess could be really faded blue???), and no ground in the metal device box. It does NOT appear as though the metal box is grounded. It's an old house (pre-1960) but has had several diy remodels, so a mixture of old/newer wiring I think… and I assume the yellow/black cable is probably original, since it's not the white/black/ground I'm used to seeing in the other areas of the house I've looked at. With everything separated, afaict, my volt pen was indicating the YELLOW was the live wire. What does yellow wire mean typically in older wiring? I always thought black was supposed to be the hot wire?
2. Here’s where I probably sound like a rookie… or maybe I don’t understand how my little pen-style voltage detector works… but after taking off the wallplate, with the light switch OFF, my pen lights up as soon as I get close to the box at all… I don’t even have to get close to the terminals on the switch. However, when I flip the switch ON, all the kitchen lights go on and the pen doesn’t light up AT ALL… even with direct contact to the terminals (see pics). I was not expecting this? Every other time I’ve used the pen, I kind of just thought it would light up near live wires, period. What stupid thing do I not understand?

[image: diagram-switch-cooktop]
<sup>Click to embiggen</sup>

[image: switch-off-volt-pen]

[image: switch-on-volt-pen]
[image: conduit-nipple]

Comment: Can you post a photo showing where the wires exit the top of the switchbox please?

Comment: 99.999% chance that if you take a picture showing us the wires exiting the box as TPE requested, we'll see a conduit nipple. In conduit, hot wires are any colors _except_ White, Grey, and Green. You don't see a green or bare because the conduit itself is acting as the grounding path. However, the pics are still needed for proof.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Its a bit of a word jambalaya at the moment.

Comment: @FreeMan -- Added pic of wires exiting the box. One thing I don't understand though... I assumed what y'all are saying was the case (that the box was grounded), but I thought when you attach a Multimeter to a hot wire and an earth ground, it should show ~120V. But when I attached the red multimeter probe to the yellow and touched the black probe to the box, it read 0.0V?

Comment: **NCV fails to still detect voltage once the circuit is loaded?** - I wanna say I've seen that happen; don't know why it does. But it doesn't matter. If you're doing the fixture (and it's not a switched neutral) you can just turn the switch off to do work. If you're messing with the switch, the breaker should be off and an NCV wouldn't do anything anyway. - An NCV tells you not to touch stuff in there, and obviously *cannot* be relied upon to detect the important part : potential.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/47653/23295

Answer (score 3):

### Yellow is hot and black is switched-hot *at this location*

That circuit, at the very least, and perhaps the rest of your house as well, is wired using metal *conduit*.  This means two things:

1. Properly installed metal conduit is a highly effective grounding path, so your box likely *is* grounded even though there's no ground wire there
2. Electricians working in conduit have the rainbow at their disposal instead of being limited to the fixed color schemes of cabling (save for white and grey, which are reserved for neutrals, and green, which is saved for grounding wires).  As a result, you will see multiple hot and/or switched-hot wires distinguished by color in conduit jobs, where they'd all otherwise be the same color (or retagged) in places using cable wiring methods.

### As to your volt detector...

As to why your NCV does not detect voltage with the switch ON, it's because a NCV is designed to detect a static potential, basically, as a "quick check" for live parts.  With current flowing, the NCV doesn't see anything because the path it completes to do that detection (a very high impedance path) is effectively shorted out by the load (obviously a low impedance path).

Comment: So, the thing I'm (still) confused about is that everyone says the metal box/conduit/nipple means the box itself is grounded. Is there a way to be sure? Because I tested with my multimeter, and I'm getting unexpected results... Attaching the black multimeter probe to a known, good ground on another circuit, the red probe gives me these readings: YELLOW wire: ~120V, BLACK wire: 0.0
But moving the black probe to the box, I get: YELLOW: 0.0, BLACK: 0.0
If the box was grounded (properly), wouldn't I expect to get 120V like I did with a known "good" ground??

Comment: Sounds like no ground there. Looking at the 70s era lock nut, and that it's an old work box, I'd say that's BX (FMC), and is *so not grounded* that it can't even light up a meter. - Possible 'switched neutral' - or they just did the colors backwards.

Comment: Yeah, there's an off chance this is a switched neutral, but more than likely something's messed up in the conduit system, thus breaking the grounding path. (Either that, or the conduit changes to another wiring method upstream)

Comment: @Dura says they're "and adding a light fixture" in [their next question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/245639/switch-on-black-is-hot-switch-off-both-black-and-white-are-hot). If we're tearing open walls now, I'd like to see it all re-done back to wherever that break in the EMT (which I don't think it is) or that *'other wiring method'*.

Answer (score 0):

In old house wiring from that era, the wall switch interrupts the hot wire. So those 2 wires in the box are both hot, interrupted by the switch. No neutral or ground in there. Based on your measurements, it looks like the metal box is not grounded. Try connecting one end of your probe to a known grounded outlet.

Some houses were wired with Hot going directly to the light fixture, then to the switch to interrupt it. That's a really bad design because the hot wire is always live in the light fixture, whether or not the wall switch is open/closed. Be careful!

Comment: > "So those 2 wires are both hot..."  
When I have everything separated, my volt pen would *only* light when I touched the YELLOW, but when I touch the BLACK, it did nothing... if they were both "hot" wires carrying current... wouldn't they both light my pen up? (Again, maybe I'm not understanding how the pen detects voltage?)

Comment: That's disappointing because it should be: black is always-hot, and yellow is the switch leg. Sounds like it's backwards (which is fine; they *could* be both black). - At that point I get my *real* meter out and find which is actually the incoming and which is the leg - but again it doesn't matter (nothing is pig tailed or goes anywhere else). Also, nice drywall screw holding it in ;) - but forget about that. The threads are all messed up now; just put it back like that. - "flickering light" (seeing the switch) I'd be looking for a bootleg ground at the fixture.

Comment: @pmont -- Yeah, I didn't have nothin' to do with the drywall screw haha... but, as you say, the threads are screw'd (pun intended) so... it is what it is :/ ... DIYers before stackexchange and youtube did some weird stuff lol

Comment: The switch interrupts hot. The hot can go to the switch first, or to the light first. Either way, one leg at the switch should always be hot, and the other will either be floating (switch open) or hot (switch closed). If one side never shows voltage, the switch may have gone bad. Use a multimeter to check continuity. If you don't have a multimeter, invest in one, you'll get a lot of use out of it.