How do I replace a sink disposal if there's no power outlet?
I don't think this would be something I can fix myself, specially because most of the garbage disposals on sale right now come with their power cord which you can connect to a power outlet under the sink. I don't see any power outlet under the sink; I see a power cord that goes through the wall and I think it goes to the power breaker.
Is it possible to replace this leaking garbage disposal with another one that has the same power diagram and if so, how? My guess is that I could reuse the power cable to connect the new garbage disposal, but not sure, now that I see new garbage disposals to buy online I only see they all come with their power cables that you connect to a power outlet, so not sure if that is not something they sell anymore.
The current garbage disposal I have is the Insinkerator Badger 9.
And here are some photos of under the sink:



As a side note - this is a great thing you have in the US. It is unfortunately forbidden to use sink disposals in France and they are so useful.

There are two ways to connect many appliances:
Cord/Plug
This has certain advantages (easy to unplug for servicing) and disadvantages (until relatively recently, cord/plug attached appliances in a kitchen or certain other rooms required GFCI protection, hardwired appliances did not). Note that a cord uses cordage which is flexible and designed to be moved around.
Hardwired
This uses either conduit or armored cable or, most commonly, non-metallic cable, a.k.a., Romex (a major brand). I prefer hardwired appliances as it removes one point of failure (the plug/receptacle). An appliance that is fixed in place (oven, cooktop, dishwasher, disposal) can generally be hardwired as the cable does not need to move around during use.
In fact, the Badger 5 installation manual shows a hardwired connection, though cord/plug connections are quite common for disposals. A Badger 5, as with many other appliances, includes a junction box within the appliance for attaching the cable (whether cord or NM cable).
I have two Badger 5s (and I replaced one of them several years ago) and they are hardwired. Note that while disposals do generally need to have GFCI protection in new installations, if your existing disposal did not have GFCI protection and it was not required at the time of installation then you do not need to add GFCI protection now, though you can if you want to do so. (Some details below. Ask a new question for more details if you want to do that.)
So what you have is a perfectly normal setup. To install:

Turn off the circuit breaker that powers the disposal
Make 100% certain the power is off. A non-contact voltage tester such as this Klein from Amazon:


is a good way to make sure power is off.

Follow the manufacturer's instructions for the rest of the installation process.

GFCI
GFCI can be provided at:

Circuit Breaker - You may already have this. If your circuit breaker has lights and a TEST button then it is either AFCI or GFCI (or possibly both).
Receptacle - This is what many people think is the only way to have GFCI. A combination duplex receptacle and GFCI protection.
Dead Front - This is the same size as a duplex receptacle but doesn't have a place to plug anything in.

A disposal can be protected by any of these. Each has advantages and disadvantages:

Breaker - Simplest configuration, works with hardwired or receptacle and always protects everything on the circuit.
Receptacle - Convenient reset button when needed. Can be used with hardwired loads if installed correctly and plug-in loads. Does not always work well with switches before the GFCI.
Dead Front - Convenient reset button when needed. Does not always work well with switches before the GFCI.

Note that if a circuit has hardwired loads that are more than 50% of the circuit capacity then it can't have any ordinary receptacles for plug-in loads on the same circuit. A Badger 5 uses 6.3 Amps, so that's fine even on a 15A circuit. But an Insinkerator Power 900 uses 9.5 Amps, so that's OK hardwired along with receptacles on a 20A circuit but not on a 15A circuit.
Note also that if you use a duplex receptacle (standard for GFCI/receptacle and most common in general) then you should wire it up to switch only the disposal receptacle. Otherwise the other receptacle only works when the disposal is running.

It looks like the OP currently has unsecured "romex" out in the open. Should that be replaced in order to be "code-legal"?

@brhans That's normal from what I have seen under a sink cabinet.

It's common, but still probably a code violation.  Personally, it'd be better to use that cable and install a GFCI outlet on the wall (any exposed cable can be raceway-ed).  Most, if not all, new disposals will come with a cord.

About the ncvt: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14080/is-a-negative-reading-from-a-non-contact-voltage-detector-sufficient

Additionally, I'd add the outlet because the next time you need to replace the disposal, you can just unplug the old one and plug in the new one, instead of having to futz around with unscrewing the dead GD's cover panel, removing the cable, replacing the cable, etc.  Do the work now to save you the work later.

Unprotected NM cable inside the cabinet is not an acceptable wiring method; the NM should terminate within a listed electrical box. This should have either a properly connected armored cable (BX) connection (if direct wired) or a receptacle in appropriate electrical box with a plug and cord whip.

Basic house wiring is a skill you should learn. It opens many doors for small convenience improvements in your home. It also helps you notice and investigate potential safety issues.
In this case, it's a fairly simple thing to repurpose the cable you have to add an outlet on the back wall. Then you're free to install a modern disposal unit.
After picking up the fundamentals of AC house wiring you'll want to learn how to:

Disconnect the circuit at the breaker panel or fuse box
Install a suitable junction box on the wall, screwing it into a stud
Secure the cable to the wall and in the box with a clamp
Strip the cable jacket and wire insulation appropriately inside the box
Connect and mount a GFCI outlet
Install a suitable cover plate

There are resources for all of this to be found, much of it on this site. If you'd like help with any aspect of it, ask more questions. We have plenty of DIYers with lots of experience around, as well as some gen-yoo-wine electricians.


www.lowes.com/n/how-to/install-a-garbage-disposal

+1. Photo is worth 1000 words. To add slightly more information - that "hardwired" connections is just "wire nuts under a little panel held with a tiny screw". This is where you disconnect/reconnect the wires when you replace it. Usually you also connect a ground wire.

Note the green wire there, which would be the ground wire.

Links to other sites are not considered proper answers on SE networks. See [answer]. Your post needs to contain some words, partly for those who can't see the image, but mostly just for the sake of completeness.

Personally, I would put a proper GFCI outlet in the wall under the sink, and plug the new disposer into that.  (If you don't feel confident handling electricity, hire a licensed electrician.)

You've basically repeated what's in two existing answers here.
